# Linearized gravity and symmetries

Tags: general-relativity, symmetry, metric-tensor

I have naive question.

When we analyzing weak gravity field we introduce expression for metric tensor as
$$
g_{\mu \nu} = \eta_{\mu \nu} + h_{\mu \nu}, \quad \eta_{\mu \nu} = diag(1, -1, -1, -1), \quad h_{\mu \nu} = \varepsilon c_{\mu \nu}, 
$$ 
where $\varepsilon$ is small parameter. But $c_{\mu \nu}$ also can't be equal to the great value, so "linearization" condition somehow limits the functional relationship of $h_{\mu \nu}$ if it depends on coorditates. Also linearized gravity laws look like Maxwell's equations. So there is the next question: do linearized gravity laws act in space-time with some symmetries (like isotropy), which doesn't exist in a case when we don't linearize gravitational interaction?

Comment: Comment to the question (v1): In principle one may consider linerized gravity $g_{\mu\nu}=g^{(0)}_{\mu\nu}+h_{\mu\nu}$ around any (background) solution $g^{(0)}_{\mu\nu}$ to Einstein's equations. The background metric $g^{(0)}_{\mu\nu}$ does not have to have Killing symmetries or be the Minkowski metric.